# Loop with df.head()

Tags: python, pandas

**Beginner**

I want to add a loop for each time the input is yes it adds 5 to the number of  df.head()

```
while True :
    check = input(' Do You Wish to continue yes/no')
    if check != 'yes' :
        break

    else :
        print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: So add a loop: `check = 'yes'`, `while check == 'yes'`

Comment: What do you mean by "adds 5 rows to the df.head()`? You're just printing the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of df.head(5) is that it shows the first 5 rows of the dataframe.
It wont add any number of rows in a loop. You need to use a variable

I think you mean this program to work in the following manner :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

i = 5
#df.shape[0] gives the number of rows
while(i< df.shape[0]):
    check = input(' Do You Wish to continue yes/no:   ')
    if check == 'yes' :
        print(df.head(i))
        i+=5#increment 5

    else :
         #if input is not 'yes' end loop
         break;
```